# Continuity of solutions in initial conditions follows from existence and uniqueness of solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

**1-** Let $f\colon E\to E$ be continuous with $f(x)\leq M$. For each $n = 1,2,..$, and let $x_n:[0,1]\rightarrow E$  be a solution of $x'= f(x)$. If $x_n(0)$ converges show that a subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges uniformly to a solution.

**2-** Use Problem 1 to show that continuity of solutions in initial conditions follows from uniqueness and existence of solutions.

I have already proved **1** using Arzelà–Ascoli theorem. But I am not sure how to use **1** to prove **2**.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show in 2 that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges when $x_n(0)$ converges.

> Note that if you take two sublimits, then by the uniqueness of solutions (assumed in 2) and since sublimits are solutions, the two sublimits are necessarily equal.

That is, the sequence $(x_n)$ converges when $x_n(0)$ converges. That's continuity.